# Failed to generate scripts for Sql Azure database: "Getting the list of objects from : failed"

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621790.aspx instructions and on get the following error:

> Getting the list of objects from 'MYDBNAME'.  Failed
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException: Failed to retrieve data for this request. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.InvalidVersionEnumeratorException: Operation not supported on version 11.0 SqlAzureDatabase. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.XmlReadDoc.LoadFile(Assembly a, String strFile) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObject.LoadInitData(String file, ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectCache.LoadElement(ObjectLoadInfo oli, ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectCache.GetElement(ObjectLoadInfo oli, ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectCache.GetAllElements(Urn urn, ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType, Object ci) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetObjectsFromCache(Urn urn, Object ci) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

How to get azure database backup or sql scripts?

UPDATE:
Azure db: SQL Server 11.0.2065;
Sql management studio: 11.0.2100.60

UPDATE 2:

SQL Azure Migration Wizard reports:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Operation not supported on version 11.0 SqlAzureDatabase. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum)

The same [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/906b4e3e-3db4-460c-bb6a-bf57e5f01e3c/).

The collation is Cyrillic_General_CI_AS. How to change collation for the db to make scripts?

UPDATE 3:

The same error while making export of Data-Tier Application using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj650016.aspx):

> ..Operation not supported on version 11.0 SqlAzureDatabase.

Answer (score 3):

In SqlServer Management Studio 2012;

Right click on the DB and Tasks > Deploy Database to Sql Azure but select your local server as target. It will get copy of azure to your local. And then you can generate scripts from your local server. I just found this method, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) as it is far more advanced than the Generate Scripts task in SSMS. As a side note, this tool is written and maintained by a person from the SQL Azure team!

Comment: It appears that you are using some of the unsupported features like SqlEnum from what I see in the last error provided.

Comment: i think your collation is not SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Because i have same problem too, with Turkish_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did the exporting of my azure db using [cloudservices.red-gate.com](http://cloudservices.red-gate.com). I created BACPAC File on a storage. Then i imported the BACPAC to my local Sql express. Strangely enough the service didn't threw the error i had when used my SQL Management Studio.