# Generate SQL scripts from Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

When I tried to Generate scripts in `SQL Server Management Studio 2012` from my `Azure` database. I received following error:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptPublishException:
>   An error occurred while scripting the objects. --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.EnumeratorException: Failed to
>   retrieve data for this request. --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.InvalidVersionEnumeratorException:
>   Operation not supported on version 11.0 SqlAzureDatabase. at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.XmlReadDoc.LoadFile(Assembly a,
>   String strFile) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObject.LoadInitData(String file,
>   ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectCache.LoadElement(ObjectLoadInfo
>   oli, ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectCache.GetElement(ObjectLoadInfo
>   oli, ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ObjectCache.GetAllElements(Urn
>   urn, ServerVersion ver, DatabaseEngineType databaseEngineType, Object
>   ci) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetObjectsFromCache(Urn
>   urn, Object ci) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request
>   req, Object ci) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object
>   connectionInfo, Request request) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object
>   connectionInfo, Request request) --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace --- at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object
>   connectionInfo, Request request) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorData(Request
>   req) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.GetLCIDCollation(String
>   collationName) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetComparerFromCollation(String
>   collationName) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean
>   inServer) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database.PreInitChildLevel() at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitChildLevel(Urn
>   levelFilter, ScriptingPreferences sp, Boolean forScripting) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabasePrefetchBase.InitializeObjectCollection(String
>   type) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabasePrefetchBase.d__1.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscoverer.SfcChildrenDiscovery(HashSet`1
>   discoveredUrns) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyDiscoverer.Discover(IEnumerable`1
>   urns) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Discover(IEnumerable`1
>   urns) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1
>   urns) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1
>   urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Script(Urn[] urns,
>   ISmoScriptWriter writer) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptGenerator.DoScript(ScriptOutputOptions
>   outputOptions) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)

I found this thread: [Failed to generate scripts for Sql Azure database: "Getting the list of objects from : failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712531/failed-to-generate-scripts-for-sql-azure-database-getting-the-list-of-objects)
but I cannot use: `http://cloudservices.red-gate.com/`

Comment: Just checking that you've followed all of the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621790.aspx

Comment: @MatthewSteeples: That link now says that "This topic is no longer available".

Comment: @eksortso: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't remember what the article said now. Are you seeing this problem with the latest version of the tools? SSMS is now available as a free standalone product.

Comment: @MatthewSteeples: I'm just referring to the MSDN link that was provided. If it's still available on MSDN I don't know where they are.

Comment: @eksortso: try https://web.archive.org/web/20140510071643/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621790.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try using third party tools for SQL Server that are able to work with Azure. I think SQL Compare from Red-Gate had the ability to work with SQL Azure but I’m not 100% sure. You can always use it in trial mode to get the job done…

Comment: I work for Red Gate and can confirm that SQL Azure is a supported data source for both SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure Migration wizard might be an option for you as well.

http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/